# Customize citation style to include notes field

Tags: bibliographies, citing, notes

I would like to include a table in my document that pulls in all the notes from the `bibitem`s in my bibliography.

So each row in the table would have a column for the citation `\cite{myitem}` and for the notes `\citenotes{myitem}`.

How do I define a `citenotes` command that would only pull in the `notes` field for that `bibitem`?

Comment: The details you provide are a bit confusing. You mention that there are `\bibitem`s in the bibliography section. This suggests that you're building the bibliography by hand, rather than let BibTeX (or biblatex/biber) do the job for you. If this impression is correct, there wouldn't be any special notes fields to extract. Maybe I'm missing something? Please consider providing a MWE (minimum working example) of your document setup.